# How can I center couples lines of text vertically?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center some 3 lines text vertically on this example that i am playing with

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html#

But i noticed I cannot use `line-height` or `height` in this situation. Is there any other way of vertically centering without using height or line height?

//this code below doesnt  work right

```
.node {line-height:8em;}
.node p {display:inline;display:inline-table;display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: What didn't work about `line-height`?

Comment: for example it  also moves the group title to the center of the other node. for example "Incobus","Kram" etc will move to the node below -- whihc break the treemap inaway

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 3):

You could try `display:table` and `vertical-align:middle`

So, it would be something like

```
.node{
    display:table;
}

.node p{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Not sure it would work given the current layout of the example.